# What does this 'Each that we lose takes part of us' quote from Emily Dickinson mean?

Tags: meaning, emily-dickinson

> Each that we lose takes part of us;
>   A crescent still abides,
>   Which like the moon, some turbid night,
>   Is summoned by the tides.
>    <sub>Emily Dickinson</sub>

What does this mean?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you were trying to ask here. Since you put the [[tag:meaning]] tag on the question, I'm assuming that you're asking for an interpretation of the quote. I've edited the post to reflect that. If I misinterpreted what you're trying to ask, please [edit] to explain what you're asking. I'd also advise you to look at the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

The missing portion of the quote is "loved one." When we lose someone we love, a portion (the "crescent") remains. She extends the analogy by comparing the pangs of grief, which never quite subside, with the tidal pull of the moon on a cloudy night.